# how can I see heroku complete log file?

Tags: heroku, npm, build

My build in Heroku fail so I want to see the complete log as they mention in the build:

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:   
npm ERR! /app/.npm/_logs/****logname*****-debug.log
```

How do I get this complete log?

Comment: running $ heroku logs $ doesn't get you the right stuff?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible to access the intermediate state of a failed build.

If you use Docker, you might take advantage of the fact that [the Heroku stacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack) are available as docker images and attempt to reproduce the problem by writing a Dockerfile based on your combination of stack ([the current default one is Heroku-18](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack#heroku-18-docker-image)) and [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks).

If you cannot do that, my suggestion would be to try making the output of `npm` more verbose, to be able to debug it from the build output.